# iPhone: How to play a sound on top of the iPod sound?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to play a sound on top of the iPod music but when I enter my app the iPod sound is silenced automatically. I tried:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound; 
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,                                 
                                 sizeof (sessionCategory),
                                 &sessionCategory                                 
                                 );
```

But probably because I use RemoteIO/Audio Units to play my sound this has no effect (not sure if that's the cause, but it sure thing does nothing ... the sound still stops)

I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioSessionSetProperty returns an error, are you checking it?

You may have forgotten to call AudioSessionInitialize, something you don't need to do with the AVFoundation wrapper.

Comment: indeed, i didn't call `AudioSessionInitialize`, however, strange enough I checked at it returned no error, will choose your answer because it explains why the above code is not working

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the code in the question doesn't work, however this works:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer * avAudioPlayer;


NSString *zeroAudioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"customSound" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:zeroAudioPath];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file
                                                                 error:nil];
self.avAudioPlayer = audioPlayer;
self.avAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
[_zeroAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[_zeroAudioPlayer play];
```

Hope it will help you.